# How to fix performance problems?

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, ssl, caching

Every 4-5 days my site gets hyper slow. About 2-3 minutes to load a page. And I can't find what it is.

- I empty my source cache.
- I empty my Cloudflare cache.
- I check if an attack is going on (There are attaches all the time).
- I shutdown the Cloudflare firewall.
- I disable plugins.
- I check the traffic.
- I shutdown Wordpress heartbeat.
- I shutdown Wordpress cron.
- I ...
  And then, out of the blue the site is fast again. But I don't know what triggered that. It is shared hosting and loging is poor. So I can't check all errors. Could it be processor memory? Or a SSL mismatch between source hosting, GTranslate and Cloudflare handshakes? (Translated pages doesn't seem to be affected that much).
  I plan to migrate to VPS with PHP 7.4 but I have to do some re-coding for that.
  I am affraid that migrating a malfunctioning website results in a migrated malfuntioning website. So I like the fix the problem before I migrate.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably hosting. You seem to have a good-ish understanding of Wordpress so I doubt it's related to your theme. Too much plugins also impact greatly performances.

Comment: This question should probably better be asked/moved here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ingo, if it should, why on earth would there be a [wordpress] tag on Stack Overflow??

Comment: There are some weird tangents here, and focus on things that are very unlikely to be related and even if they were you'll be unable to address - By that I mean 'SSL mismatch between source hosting', 'Cloudflare handshakes'. Also `I empty my Cloudflare cache.` this is likely to actively make things worse. You need to focus on finding a specific actionable cause and that means reading log files, adding log statements around things suspected, identifying and eliminating causes (are static files _also_ slow, or not?) etc. The DB is normally the problem - good luck.

Comment: @MaksimKuzmin Sorry, it was my first time ever to aks a question on Stack. I wasn't aware of the green check mark function. If I did I would have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @amarinediary has already noted, it can be the hosting provider. But I'd like to add few suggestions on his point.

Shared hosting, as it derives from their name, are literally **sharing** the resources of a server to every website that it hosts. They also have limitations per website, but it's not always controllable.

If another website on the same hosting is being attacked by DDOS, it requires additional resources from the server, henceforth there's nothing left for your website. And if this is exactly what's happening, just feel free to migrate to VPS.

But there's another important reason why this might be happening. And the funny thing is that few years ago that was exactly what happening to my website, and I broke all my brains to understand what that was. And it's very simple: Search Engines Robots. I see that you're quite proficient on that topic, so I won't explain you basic things about how they work, and why do they do that. But you see, when Google or any other SE is indexing your website, it requests every single page on it, and the effect may be exactly as if it would be DDOS. And it happens every 4 - 5 days, exactly as you described.

What'd be solution to this? Give the website more resources and migrate to VPS. Or, if you want to make sure this scenario is correct, tell Google and other SE robots to make crawl less frequent. Add this to your `robots.txt`:

```
Crawl-delay: 5
```

This means that robots will request every page only once per 5 seconds.

> I plan to migrate to VPS with PHP 7.4 but I have to do some re-coding for that. I am affraid that migrating a malfunctioning website results in a migrated malfuntioning website. So I like the fix the problem before I migrate.

The worst thing happens is that you receive the same website as it was before. In any scenario, VPS is a win-win solution. Feel free to (you won't regret it).

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions so far. It makes my feelings for a VPS stronger than they already were.

Comment: I thought about the Google robot before (I disabled most others). Of course Analytics doesn't show that, but my host offers Webalizer Version 2.23. I see no extreem differences in the daily traffic there and I thought the tool shows all traffic. Or am I wrong?
(I will add the Crawl-delay, good suggestion!)

Comment: Yes, you're wrong, because all analytics tools are ignoring IPs, coming from bots.

Comment: That's what I said. I was talking about Webalizer...

Comment: Well, as I said, there're two options: Webalizer's ignoring Google Bots too, or you're being DDoS attacked. There're no other options. And I wasn't talking about GA, I was talking about literally any web traffic analyzers.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the third option: sharing hosting.

Comment: Oke, I the past I had a plugin that showed bots. I will check for a similair one.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Wim if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Glad that I helped you.